# ResultSet of two similar column names in a join query

Tags: sql, join

I am wondering how am I supposed to use a join query with the same column names from two different tables in Java ResultSet, like:

```
SELECT Table2.CustomerName,Table1.CustomerName 
  FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table2.ID=Table1.ID;
```

Thanks a head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
SELECT Table2.CustomerName as columnA,
Table1.CustomerName as columnB 
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table2.ID=Table1.ID;
```

In your Java code you can use `resultSet` as shown below:

```
resultSet.getString("columnA");
resultSet.getString("columnB");
```

Comment: Thank you very much solved.

Answer (score 0):

You're suggestion is OK, better using aliases abbreviately with your tables :

```
SELECT t1.CustomerName t1_CustomerName ,
       t2.CustomerName t2_CustomerName
  FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.ID=t1.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aliases to get unique names

```
SELECT Table2.CustomerName AS name1, Table1.CustomerName AS name2
FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table2.ID=Table1.ID;
```

You can also use them for the tables

```
SELECT t2.CustomerName AS name1, t1.CustomerName AS name2
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.ID= t1.ID;
```